# Wordpress - Paginating through a yearly archive based on category

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to paginate through a yearly archive based on a specific category, i.e.:

localhost:8080/category/press-releases/2016/

That url displays all the press releases related to year via:

```
<a href="/category/press-releases/2010">2010</a>
<a href="/category/press-releases/2011/">2011</a>
<a href="/category/press-releases/2012">2012</a>
<a href="/category/press-releases/2013">2013</a>
<a href="/category/press-releases/2014">2014</a>
<a href="/category/press-releases/2015">2015</a>
<a href="/category/press-releases/2016">2016</a>
```

And looking at my code:

```
<?php 
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE site_id = %d AND public = '1' AND archived = '0' AND mature = '0' AND spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND last_updated != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by postyear", $wpdb->siteid );
?>
    <?php $oldyear = $postyear = get_the_time('Y', $post->ID);?>
    <h4><?php echo $postyear; ?></h4>
    <ul class="archive-posts"><?php
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $postyear = get_the_time('Y', $post->ID);
        if ($oldyear != $postyear) {
            $oldyear = $postyear; ?>
            </ul><h4><?php echo $postyear; ?></h4><ul class="archive-posts">
            <?php
    } ?>
    <li><span class="archive-post-title">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
    </a></span><span class="archive-post-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span></li><?php
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

That all works fine and displays all posts related to the particular years. Ideally, what I'm trying to do is display 5 posts per page and paginate through the rest for that year. I've been working with many loops, various functions, rewrites, permalink changes, but whenever I hit the url: /category/press-releases/2016/page/2 - the result is always a 404.

If someone could point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this, it would be greatly appreciated, as I'm a bit flummoxed.

Cheers to you for reading,
~chipleh

Comment: I decided to go the route of jQuery pagination instead, wp loop pagination was seemingly too problematic with my permalinks. Regardless, if anyone has a proper php solution, I'd still love to know what it is.